# How to create a record that contains a user in Django test setUp

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-testing

I have this model in my Django application:

```py
class ClubSession(models.Model):
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    coach = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
    details = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.location
```

This view implements it:

```py
class SessionListView(ListView):
    model = ClubSession
    template_name = 'club_sessions.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_club_sessions_list'
```

I'm trying to test the view. My test class has a `setUp` which creates a record:

```py
def setUp(self):
    ClubSession.objects.create(location='test location',
                               coach=User(id=1),
                               date='2020-06-01 18:30',
                               details='this is another test')
```

When I run my test I get this error:

```
IntegrityError: The row in table 'club_sessions_clubsession' with primary key '1' has an invalid foreign key: club_sessions_clubsession.coach_id contains a value '1' that does not have a corresponding value in auth_user.id.
```

A user with id 1 exists so how do I get this to work? I've tried adding the username but that didn't work either.

Comment: Tests run on a different database, so no data exists that is in the "standard" database.

Comment: User(id=1) is not saved to the database. So it can't be linked as a foreign key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would strongly advise *not* to use primary keys, especially since dispatching primary keys is the responsibility of the database, and thus that can differ between sessions.

Furthermore tests run on an independent database, so the data stored in the database you use in development or on production is not used.

Probably it is better to first *create* a user, for example:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# …

def setUp(self):
    user = User.objects.create(username='foo')
    ClubSession.objects.create(
        location='test location',
        coach=user,
        date='2020-06-01 18:30',
        details='this is another test'
    )
```

Comment: Perfect. That was exactly what I was looking for. Good to know about the independent database. I never thought. Will accept the answer in a few minutes when I can.